# One state goes down and one doesn't

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have {onView: '0'} in the state goes down as props to my View component.
But the state {min: 0, max: 100} doesn't go down to my Range component.
Where did I go wrong?

App.js:

```
export class Generator extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        onView: '0',
        min: 0,
        max: 100
    } 
  }

  render() {
    var btnClick = () => {
      var x = Math.ceil(Math.ceil(Math.random()) / Math.random());
      return this.setState({ onView : x });
    };
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Instructions />
        <Range max={this.state.max} min={this.state.min} />
        <Generate currentClick={btnClick} />
        <View show={this.state.onView} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

View Component:

```
 const View = ({ show }) => {
   return (
    <div className="view">
    <h1>{show}</h1>
    </div>
   );
 }

export default View;
```

Range component:

```
class Range extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="rangeDiv">
        <input type="text" value={this.min}/>
        <input type="text" value={this.max}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Range;
```

I would appreciate any help here, thanks!

Comment: because you're using `this.min` instead of `this.props.min`?

Answer (score 2):

try this out please! I guess you missed the props there

```
<input type="text" value={this.props.min}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `this.min` instead of `this.props.min` and the same for `max`.
Try this:

```
class Range extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const { min, max } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="rangeDiv">
        <input type="text" value={min} />
        <input type="text" value={max} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Range;
```